# Does not work zip from exec()

Tags: php, cron, zip, exec

I have php script that is run from cron. There are such command as

```
zip -j9 {targer_some_directory}/all.zip {some_directory}/pdf/*.pdf
```

in that script.

This command is running by exec();

{some_directory} and {targer_some_directory} are existing full path. These directories have rights = 0777.
When I run this script from shell it works. When it run from cron, script doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

When you run script from `shell` and from `cron` you have a different content for a `$PATH` environment variable.
So, I suppose your zip located in some place, which does't included into cron's $PATH.

The very simplest solution is to run zip with specifying full path, for instance `/usr/local/bin/zip`